# Saving xlsx file in csv tranform simple quote to triple quote (since today)

Tags: excel, csv, quote

Since today, excel interprets the data of my xlsx file to add additional quote in the csv file.
It's anonying since I want only one quote for some columns and none for others.

I didnt have this problem before.

For instance :
text1;"text2"  becomes  text1;"""text2"""

I know that I can replace the triple quote  in the output file with one quote, but cant I desactivate an option or whatever to avoid this ?

In the same way, when I save in csv file data which has been interpretaed by excel (like cells in number format instead of standard), the csv file keeps the excel format instead of saving sourcing data.
For example, 0 is "-" in number format and is saving as " -    " in csv file instead of "0".

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: With regard to the doubled double-quote, CSV files usually use the double-quote as a text qualifier.  When you have certain characters within a cell (eg double-quote, linefeed, comma (or semicolon, in your case)), the CSV has to "quote" that cell in order to not misinterpret those characters.  With regard to the numbers being saved as formatted, Excel has always done it that way.  A workaround would be write your own VBA routine for saving text files. Then you would have complete flexibility as to what you wrote to the file.

Comment: Thanks for you reply
Are you sure that excel/csv has always done that way ? I never observed that before

Comment: Pretty certain. It has always been the case that a string surrounded by "single-double-quotes", eg: `"text"` would be rendered without the quotes when open'd or imported into Excel.